# cmd.exe strange behavior. Not recognizing desktop anymore

Tags: command-line, batch-file, traceroute

I was trying to add a tracert command to a .bat file.

At the cmd.exe I was writing:

```
tracert 111.111.111.111 > desktop\tracert.txt
```

and it ran ok. I've created a bat file like this:

```
::@echo off
Cd C:\
cls
echo %DATE%
echo %TIME%
set datetimef=%date:~-4%_%date:~3,2%_%date:~0,2%__%time:~0,2%_%time:~3,2%_%time:~6,2%
echo %datetimef%
::2013_04_20__13_01_47
::tracert 111.111.111.111 > desktop\Tracert_IP1_%datetimef%.txt
tracert 111.111.111.111 > desktop\tracert.txt
```

The idea is to add the data to filename, I also would like to write it inside the tracert.txt, but I dont know how.

Code result:

```
C:\>echo 20/04/2013
20/04/2013

C:\>echo 14:18:12,44
14:18:12,44

C:\>set datetimef=2013_04_20__14_18_12

C:\>echo 2013_04_20__14_18_12
2013_04_20__14_18_12

**C:\>tracert 111.111.111.111  1>desktop\tracert.txt**
**The system cannot find the path specified**
```

Why is it adding "1" before the ">" and removing the space between ">" and "desktop"?

### Anyway, I tried to run the `tracert` command again directly at the cmd but now it is giving me the same error message as the bat file:  `The system cannot find the path specified`

Edit 1:
Well, the problem with the path not find is because I've changed the cmd path using "cd" command, than the desktop folder was just not found! I'm embarrassed! Sorry guys.. 
Thanks for the replays about the "1"s and disapearing withe spaces.

Comment: To remove all ambiguity why not specify the full path, with quotes if required?

Comment: I'd probably use %USERPROFILE%\Desktop

Comment: You are right! Dumb problem.. sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The place you know as `desktop` is a subfolder of your user profile that has the same name.  If your batch file is stored on your desktop then simply remove the `desktop\` part of the output.  When you run `cmd` its base directory is your root user profile directory which has your desktop folder below that.  If you create a batch file and run it then the base directory that `cmd` works in is *that* directory and not your user profile.

If you want your batch file to always output to your desktop irrespective of where it is stored then the `cmd` environment has a variable `USERPROFILE` that points to your profile directory (`C:\Users\yourUserName`) and can be combined with `\desktop` to output files to your desktop.

Where you have

```
tracert 111.111.111.111 > desktop\tracert.txt
```

Replace it with

```
tracert 111.111.111.111 > %USERPROFILE%\desktop\tracert.txt
```

Comment: Yes, that's what I'd say. Alternatively, one can also create an environment variable for this user's desktop folder... so it can be accessed via for ex: `%DESKTOP%`

Answer (score 3):

"Desktop" in this case is relative path. You should change to right folder ("cd" command) or put the whole path to output file in the .bat file.

Comment: If the path contains spaces - you should specify the whole path surrounded by "".

Answer (score 1):

`1>` is STDOUT, as opposed to STDERR, which is `2>`

I think the space is just a syntactical issue, cmd.exe doesn't like the whitespace, so it changes it.

See Microsoft's [Command redirection](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx?mfr=true) page for more info.

As to the not found error, checking permissions in that directory would be my first suggestion.

PS: Not a win user anymore, but is 'desktop' a valid way of accessing the desktop, or is it a directory name?

Comment: I realizy that I was very dumb! Lol... When you start cmd it starts by default at the Users\UserName folder! I changed the cmd path usind "cd".. LOL! sorry!